# which are alternative of tofixed() in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there other alternative ways of toFixed in javascript?.

I want alternative way of toFixed() which doesn't allow rounding number.

For Example
Exp: `12.4567` after appling tofixed(2) it will convert to `12.46`.

but I want `12.45`

Comment: `string.match(/\d+\.\d{1,2}/)[0]`

Comment: `Math.floor(yourNumber*100)/100` for positive numbers and `Math.ceil(yourNumber*100)/100` for negative ones